# Web-service authentication management

Tags: web-services, security, session, authentication

I'll have to develop some private **web-services**, so I need a way to **authenticate** the users in order for each service to be able to know if a request is valid and to maintain some session states.

I'd like to have a central authentication service with some simple operations like "**logIn(login, password)**" (that uses a **directory** like **LDAP**), "**isValidSession(sessionID)**" and "**logOut(sessionID)**". The "**logIn**" operation should generate a **session ID**, or something similar, that would allow a user to communicate further with the other services by using this token.

Then when a user tries to use an operation :

- the user provides as the last parameter its session ID,
- the operation asks the authentication server if the provided ID is valid,
- if yes the operation retrieves user's session informations,
- the operation proceeds and return the result.

**Does it exist standard patterns and technologies to manage this kind of scenario ?**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, it exists with Spring Check this http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/security.html

Comment: Thanks for this useful information; so it seems WS-Security could be the solution I'm looking after.

Answer (score 2):

Before setting up something *custom*, have you considered something like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) at all?

Comment: thanks for looking at this issue. Indeed OAuth may be another solution to consider when the issue will be put on the agenda again.